# Set file save type on vcard in MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, file-type, vcf-vcard

I created an MVC page which returns a vCard (Response.ContentType = "text/vcard";). The param that I pass in on the URL route is the user's account name (the first part of their e-mail address). When I hit the page, I get a dialog box prompting to save the file, but the file type of the Save dialog box is also the user's account name, when it should be .VCF. How can I set the default file type in the Save dialog box to be .VCF?

Thanks,
Jay

Comment: You should just be using `return File(content, "text/vcard", "somefilename.vcf")` in your controller.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set `Content-Disposition` to `attachment; filename=SOmeName.vcf`